# No logging with starting bluemix container

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud, dockerfile

I create a bluemix container with a docker file.
If I look at the IBM dashboard the status of the container is fixed on Networking.

When I try to get the log file through bij cf ic in my command shell I get a 404.

I use the following command the get the container_id: `cf ic ps -a`.
This is the response I get back:
`CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                 PORTS   NAMES
57f7363b-710        <no image>          ""                  8 days ago          Networking a day ago   XXX.YYY.ZZZ.KKK:22->22/tcp, XXX.YYY.ZZZ.KKK:80->80/tcp, XXX.YYY.ZZZ.KKK:587->587/tcp, XXX.YYY.ZZZ.KKK:2812->2812/tcp   containername`

With the following command I try to get the logs: `cf ic logs 57f7363b-710`.

But then I see the following response:

```
FAILED

404 error encountered while processing request!`
```

Is there another way to see why the container is hanging on the status "Networking"?

Answer (score 4):

This issue reflects a networking problem that has been fixed last week. When the container status is freeze you can use "ICE rm -f" to force the removal of a running container or "ICE stop" to stop a running container by sending SIGTERM and then SIGKILL after a grace period.
If you are unable to create a new container because the status is always "freeze", please open a ticket to bluemix support.

Answer (score 3):

When a container is in '*Networking*' state it means that the networking phase is not finished yet. During that step of a container creation there is for example the allocation of selected IP addresses (both public and private). When this phase ends you will be able to route requests to those IPs. When a container is in '*Networking*' state for too long it usually means that there was an **infrastructure problem**. You can try to create a new container from the same image with *cf ic run*. Please consider that if you reached the maximum quota you could need to delete the stuck container or to release unbound IPs in order to create a new one. 
You can delete a container using:

> cf ic rm -f *[containerId]*

You can list all IPs (available or not) using:

> cf ic ip list -a

Then you can release an IP using:

> cf ic ip release *[IPAddr]*